# Compile a package against different kernel headers?

Tags: systemd, kernel, kernel-modules, make

I have a set of kernel headers that I want to build against in `/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/...`

Is it possible to have make wholesale just look for kernel headers there or do they need to be installed to the normal `/usr/local` or `/usr` areas?

I'm trying to build `systemd` for `libudev` (pretty sure I only need `libudev` but it's incorporated into `systemd`).

Answer (score 0):

you can write a `Makefile` and use `make` utility.

something like this in `Makefile` would work:

```
make -c /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd)
```

Cannot add comments due to less reputation, so writing here..